# Asymptotics for square-free numbers in an arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Set 
$$Q(s,\chi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)^2\chi(n)}{n^s},\quad (s=\sigma+i\tau),$$
where $\chi$ is a character $\mod q$, 
Show that $Q(s,\chi)=L(s,\chi)H(s,\chi)$ where $H(s,\chi)$ is a bounded, holomorphic function for $\sigma\geqslant \sigma_0>\frac{1}{2}$. Show that $L(s,\chi)\ll_{\varepsilon} (Tq)^{1-\sigma+\varepsilon}$ for $0\leqslant \sigma\leqslant 1$, $|\tau|+1 \leqslant T$ and deduce that, for all $\varepsilon>0$ and uniformly for $x\geqslant 2$, $q\geqslant1$, $(a,q)=1$, one has
$$\sum_{\substack{n\leqslant x \\ n \equiv a \pmod q}} \mu(n)^2 =\frac{x}{q} \prod_{p \nmid q}(1-p^{-2}) + O_{\varepsilon}\big(x^{2/3+\varepsilon} q^{1/3}\big). \qquad\quad(1)$$ 
I find this problem in G.Tenenbaum's book in the page 265.
Gérald Tenenbaum. Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1995.

I can get that

By [Euler's Product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) 
$$Q(s,\chi)=\prod_{p}\Big(1+\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\Big)=\frac{L(s,\chi)}{L(2s,\chi^2)},$$
$$|\mu(n)^2\chi(n)|\leqslant 1, \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu(n)^2\chi(n)|}{n^\sigma} \leqslant \zeta(\sigma)$$
so $H(s,\chi)=1/L(2s,\chi^2)$ is a bounded, holomorphic function for $\sigma\geqslant \sigma_0>\frac{1}{2}$.

By [Perron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula)
$$\sum_{n\leqslant x}\mu(n)^2\chi(n) =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{L(s,\chi)}{L(2s,\chi^2)}\frac{x^s}{s}\mathrm{d}s +O\Big(\frac{x^c}{T}\Big).$$
Then how can I do? How to prove $(1)$?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks! I have updated the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Perron's formula, I will use one of the simplest and most versatile tricks in analytic number theory - the fact that the sum over the [Mobius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) is $1$  when $n=1$, and $0$  otherwise.That is, we will use the fact that: $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$  If I am not mistaken, this approach results in a significantly better error term than the one quoted in your question.

Since $\mu^{2}(n)$ is the indicator function for the squarefree numbers, it follows from our Möbius identity that $\sum_{d^{2}|n}\mu(d)=\mu^{2}(d).$ Let $$Q(x;q,a)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
n\leq x\\
n\equiv a\ (q)
\end{array}}\mu^{2}(n).$$ Inserting this identity and switching the order of summation we have $$Q(x;q,a)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
n\leq x\\
n\equiv a\ (q)
\end{array}}\sum_{d^{2}|n}\mu(d)=\sum_{d^{2}\leq x}\mu(d)\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
n\leq x:\ d^{2}|n\\
n\equiv a\ (q)
\end{array}}1.$$ For the inner sum, $$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
k\leq x/d^{2}\\
k\equiv d^{-2}a\ (q)
\end{array}}1=\frac{x}{qd^{2}}+O(1),$$ when $d$  is relative prime to $q$, and $0$ otherwise, and so $$Q(x;q,a)=\frac{x}{q}\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
d^{2}\leq x\\
(d,q)=1
\end{array}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}+O\left(\frac{\phi(q)}{q}x^{1/2}\right).$$ Now $$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
d^{2}\leq x\\
(d,q)=1
\end{array}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}=\prod_{p\nmid q}\left(1-p^{-2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$ so we obtain the final result:

> $$Q(x;q,a)=\frac{x}{q}\prod_{p\nmid q}\left(1-p^{-2}\right)+O\left(x^{1/2}\right) .$$