# Density of Squarefree 1 degree polynomial

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

> Let a > 0, b be coprime integers. Find the density of integers
> n for which $an + b$ is squarefree.

This question is from assignment 2 of  Zeev Rudnick's Lecture notes: [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)

I have read till lecture 11 but I am not sure which result I should use( relevant material can be found in Lecture 5-6) because the result over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are conjectures only although results over $F_{q} [t]$ are theorems.

So, can you please tell which results I should use to find density.

Comment: Do the notes give a proof of the theorem that says that the density of integers $n$ for which $n$ is squarefree is $6/\pi^2$? If so, maybe you can find a way to modify that proof to work for $an+b$.

Comment: Making any progress, James?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for replying late. The notes don't give such a theorem.

Comment: Warlimont, R. On squarefree numbers in arithmetic progressions. Monatshefte für Mathematik 73, 433–448 (1969). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01316664 might have an answer. It's behind a paywall, but if you have access to an academic library they might have a subscription to the journal, or they might be able to get it for you on interlibrary loan. Here's another paper behind a paywall: A Note on Square-Free Numbers in Arithmetic Progressions C. Hooley Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 7, Issue 2, July 1975, Pages 133–138, https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/7.2.133

Comment: I can't vote-to-close as a duplicate, but I think you'll find an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226663/asymptotics-for-square-free-numbers-in-an-arithmetic-progression also at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092550/the-density-of-square-free-integers-satisfying-a-congruence-relation

Comment: Had a look at those links, James?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mate, I am not feeling well and I am on a break. Will take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: OK. Wishing you a speedy recovery.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This question is not a duplicate of the questions you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P_a$ be the set of primes that divide $a$, and let $Q_a$ be the set of all other primes. To be square free, $an+b$ must not be divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$. This holds  for every $p\in P_a$ by the coprimality of $a$ and $b$,, so we can focus on primes in $Q_a$. If $p \in Q_a$ then $a$ is invertible mod $p^2$, so the arithmetic progression $\{an+b : n \ge 0\}$ is uniformly distributed modulo $p^2$. Since divisibility by different primes is asymptotically independent, the limiting density of integers $n$ such that $an+b$ is square free equals
$$\prod_{p \in Q_a}(1-p^{-2})= \frac{\prod_{p}(1-p^{-2})}{\prod_{p \in P_a}(1-p^{-2})}=\frac{6 }{\pi^2 \prod_{p \in P_a}(1-p^{-2})}\,$$
where the last step used the Euler product formula [1] and the value of $\zeta(2)$ [2]. See [3] for how to make the independence argument rigorous.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer

Comment: "This holds for every $p\in P_a$ by the coprimality of a and b," how does it holds for all primes in $p\in P_a$?

Comment: @James If $p \in P_a$, then $p$ cannot divide $b$ by coprimality. Thus $an+b$ is not divisible by $p$, and a fortiori not divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: How did a will be invertible mod $p^2$ , if  $p\in Q_a$?

Comment: Can you also tell how exactly $p\in Q_a$ mod $p^2$, implies that A P is uniformly distributed mod $p^2$?